# AngularJS in IE8 - Error: this command is not supported

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a SPA with Angular and the app requires IE8+ support. I recently pulled a search feature out into a directive. The git commit before I added the directive works fine, so I'm certain the error was caused by the directive. Here's the directive code:

```
myApp.directive('genericSearch', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope : {
            interface: '=genericSearch'
        },
        controller: 'genericSearchController',
        template : '<input class="generic-search" placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="model.searchText" data-ng-change="beginSearch()" />',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.model = scope.interface.model || function() { };
            scope.finished = scope.interface.finished || function() { };
            scope.endpoint = scope.interface.endpoint || 'searchDirectory';
        }
    };
});
```

In my view template, the directive is initiated thus:

```
<input data-generic-search="searchInterface" />
```

Now when I navigate to a page with this directive, I get an error referencing the ng-view element:
`Error: This command is not supported.<:section class="is-scrollable ng-scope" data-ng-view="" ng-1400945355054="29">`

Any idea where this error is coming from? I've tried the HTML5 boilerplates, adding the unsupported elements, like `section`, but it was working before I added the directive so I don't think that's the issue.

**EDIT**

The directive is confirmed working in IE9+ and Chrome.
I'm guessing it's related to the input element. I've tried changing the original element to a `div`, which gets replaced by the `input` element in the directive template. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was indeed the `input` element, and changing it to `span` did the trick. Perhaps the page was cached when I tried before with `div`.

I think the issue is caused by the way IE handles input type changing and the way Angular replaces source elements for directives.